# Web Forms Timer to refresh an image is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, timer, webforms

I have a web forms application that has a function that saves an image from an IPcamera.  The I added a viewer page that is supposed to refresh the image, but it wasn't working.  I thought that maybe since the function was in the page_load so it only saved the new image when the page first loads.  I added a Timer so that every 5 seconds it would run the function that saves the new image, but the timer doesn't seem to be working.  Here is the code:

```
namespace PlayVideo
{
public partial class Video : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    FileStream fs = File.Open(@"Location of file", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);



    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //This is where I originally had the function that saves the new image.
        //string saveTo = @"location to save new image";
        //FileStream writeStream = new FileStream(saveTo, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);

        ReadWriteStream(fs, writeStream);

        Response.Clear();
        Response.TransmitFile("~/images/test.jpg");



    }

    // readStream is the stream you need to read
    // writeStream is the stream you want to write to
    private void ReadWriteStream(Stream readStream, Stream writeStream)
    {
        int Length = 256;
        Byte[] buffer = new Byte[Length];
        int bytesRead = readStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length);
        // write the required bytes
        while (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            writeStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            bytesRead = readStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length);
        }
        readStream.Close();
        writeStream.Close();
    }



    protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string saveTo = @"location to save new image";
        FileStream writeStream = File.Open(saveTo, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);

        ReadWriteStream(fs, writeStream);

        //Response.Clear();
        //Response.TransmitFile("~/images/test.jpg");
    }

}

}
```

Here is the .aspx code for the timer

```
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">

    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel4" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" ontick="Timer1_Tick" Interval="5000" >
            </asp:Timer>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and here is the code for the viewer page:

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div> 
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server"  />   
  <img src="/video.aspx" id="the_image" alt="" />  


  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

      function refreshImage() {
          objIMG = document.getElementById('the_image');
          objIMG.src = objIMG.src.substr(0, objIMG.src.indexOf('&nocache=')); +'&nocache=' + Math.random();
      }

      $(document).ready(function () {
          setInterval(refreshImage, 1000);
      })
</script>
</div>
</form>
</body>
```

It doesn't save every 5 seconds or it doesn't refresh the image, I don't know which is the problem.  Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a servier side event? You already have javascript and the `setInterval()` method.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

      function refreshImage() {
          objIMG = document.getElementById('the_image');
          objIMG.src = objIMG.src.substr(0, objIMG.src.indexOf('&nocache=')); +'&nocache=' + Math.random();
      }

      $(document).ready(function () {
          setInterval(refreshImage, 1000);
      })


</script>
```

Comment: I stated in the post that I added the viewer page but that refresh wasn't working.

Comment: what part of it isn't working? have you stepped through the javascript to see why?

Comment: apparently I need administrative privileges to debug and I don't have those on this computer.  Is there like a few lines of code I can add to the javascript to see if it is even running though the function? like "num = num +1" and display num?  I don't know javascript that is why I am asking.

Comment: You shouldnt need admin privileges to debug javascript. I would set a breakpoint on the `setInterval` line, as well as the `refreshImage()` function, to see if 1 - they are being hit, and 2 - your refresh image function runs. See this link to debug JS - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg699336(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that will break in your application, the first of which is:

```
FileStream fs = File.Open(@"C:\Users\xoswaldr\Desktop\C sharp stuff\SaveVideoToFilestream\SaveVideoToFilestream\bin\Debug\FS.avi", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
```

By putting this at the top of your `.aspx` page, you are telling the operating system that you want to open a file. This, in and of itself, is fine. But you never actually tell windows to close the file, and the stream will leak memory for the duration of the thread. Additionally, it will lock the file so that no other process can access it. The way around this to tell .NET that you only want the file for a short time. This is usually done by:

```
using(FileStream fs = File.Open(@"C:\Users\xoswaldr\Desktop\C sharp stuff\SaveVideoToFilestream\SaveVideoToFilestream\bin\Debug\FS.avi", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
    // do stuff to fs in here
} // at this } bracket, .NET will release the file
```

The using keyword is pretty important, there are better explanations of it out there than I can write but it's commonly used for IO-related tasks in .NET.

Secondly, you are instantiating a `Timer` in your .aspx page. This is a pitfall that programmers who come to ASP.NET from normal WinForms often fall into. The class that serves your .aspx page is not persistent, when you make a request to that url, your class will get instantiated, then when the request is done, it will be disposed of. So when you instantiate a `Timer`, it will run for the ~50-200 milliseconds it takes to serve your webpage. When that is all done and sent back to the browser, however, your instance will be gone as will your `Timer` (hopefully, unless there is a memory leak).

More importantly, there is no need for a `Timer` in your page class. In your viewer page, you already have a piece of javascript like

```
setInterval(refreshImage, 1000);
```

This tells the browser to make another request to your page class. So all your class really needs to do, then, is read from the file (don't forget the `using(...){}` clause from earlier), and return the result to the client.